# Telegram Bot : what message/user is the bot replying to?

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

background: I'm making a Telegram Bot for a group chat, that parses messages for specific keywords, then marks a spreadsheet per those keywords, and then sends a message to show that marking was successful or not.

Now this gets confusing when multiple messages are sent to the bot at the same time - so my question is:

Question: 
Is there a /sendMessage method for bots that replies to a certain message?
if not : is there a way to mention the user whom the bot is talking to?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: in google scripts, using java.

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How are you using Java in Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `reply_to_message_id` property in the [`sendMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) object.

Set that and the message that the bot posts should show up a s a reply to the message you received.

This will however only work if the message your bot is send is to the same chat/group that the original message came from.